# Attributes in custom modal directive not resolved

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I created a custom directive to display a ui.bootstrap modal and I cannot populate the dialog with the values I want. I don't understand why is it not working. I checked other questions and posts but I could not find and example suitable for my case.

I've created a plunker with a similar version of my real code to show the problem.
In the example, I am using a button to launch the modal but in my application I am doing it by code when some conditions are satisfied.
This is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/7CCV7uHHj7SrWbsp1PRJ

Basically I have a directive:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.directive('revModal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      id: "@",
      title: "@",
      size: "@",
      bodyMessage: '@',
      acceptButton: '@',
      dismissButton: '@'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $modal) {
      $scope.title = $scope.title ? $scope.title : "Alert";
      $scope.size = $scope.size ? $scope.size : "sm";
      $scope.acceptButton = $scope.acceptButton ? $scope.acceptButton : "OK";
      $scope.dismissButton = $scope.dismissButton ? $scope.dismissButton : "Cancel";

      $scope.openModal = function() {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'modalAlert.html',
          animation: true,
          backdrop: true,
          windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
          size: $scope.size,
          resolve: {
            acceptButton: $scope.acceptButton,
            dismissButton: $scope.dismissButton
          }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function() {}, function() {
          console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
      };
    },
    link: function($scope, element) {
      element[0].open = function() {
        return $scope.openModal();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In the directive I've also tried to resolve the values using function but it didn't work either.

```
 resolve:{
     dismissButton: function(){return $scope.dismissButton}
     ...
    }
```

The directive template is the following, and my problem is that the values inside curly braces are not replaced. The logic to link the ng-click functions was not done yet.

```
<div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      {{bodyMessage}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="acceptModal()">{{acceptButton}}</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="dismissModal()">{{dismissButton}}</button>
    </div>
```

To use this directive I just insert the following tag in the html:

```
<div ng-controller="TimeRangeModalController">
    <rev-modal id="timeRangeModal" title="test" accept-button="acepto" dismiss-button="calcelo" body-message="cuerpo"></rev-modal>
</div>
```

The controller to open the modal is:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('TimeRangeModalController', function($scope, $document) {

  $scope.open= function(modalId){
      if (undefined !== modalId) {
      var modal = $document[0].getElementById(modalId);
      if (null !== modal) {
        modal.open();
      } else {
        console.error('DOM element with id ' + 'modalId' + 'does not exist');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Any suggestion on how should I resolve the values to populate the modal?
Thanks and regards, Daniela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've discovered the issue, I was missing to set the scope in the modalInstance.
The final open modal function will be:

```
 $scope.openModal = function() {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'modalAlert.html',
          animation: true,
          backdrop: true,
          windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
          size: $scope.size,
          scope:$scope
        });
```

Note also that the resolve clause is not need it.
I've updated the Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/7CCV7uHHj7SrWbsp1PRJ